# What to do when pushing a view that's smaller than the underlying one?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have an iPhone app that's presenting a typical master/detail view, starting with a tableview. When a row is tapped, I push the view controller for that row (which is loaded from a storyboard). The views for each row are all of various sizes, some containing only a few controls.

I find that iOS doesn't push the underlying view away smoothly; if the incoming view is smaller than the current one, a fragment of the current one moves awkwardly only partly to the left and remains visible before blinking out.

[Watch the bottom here.](https://youtu.be/IHYrpbj7wlo)

That bottom bar is **not** a toolbar, by the way. It's laid out on the main view explicitly, like anything else.

Here's how the incoming view is invoked (`tabBoard` is a storyboard):

```
    if let singlePageController = tabBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: tabName) as? AtomViewController
    {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(singlePageController, animated: true)
    }
```

I could make an unnecessarily large incoming view, but this is a hokey workaround considering that I don't know the resolution of the user's device or of future devices.  And there's no way I can see of making the topmost view auto-resize to the safe area. I've set autoresizing to expand the view, but no dice.

I've also tried setting the incoming view controller's view frame to equal the current safe area.  The frame size is changed (to one that indeed looks full-screen), but the transition is still messy.

What gives?

[image]

Comment: I'm not updating anything yet; just pushing the view onto the stack.

Comment: O sorry, I just concentrated on the "Sata SSD" stuff, but now I see the tabbar animation. Just forget my comments.

Comment: If you want to keep the master view controller in view beneath the detail view controller, why don’t you present it? This kind of behavior is not what the navigation controller was intended for. This is typical modal behavior.

Comment: I don't want to keep it in view.

Answer (score 0):

Please check these boxes in the ViewController setting.

1. Hide bottom bar on push
2. Use Full Screen

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. "Use full screen" (aside from being deprecated) made no difference.  And under "Presentation," one of the options is "full screen."  That doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the solution was to make sure the incoming view's background color wasn't set to "clear."  Setting all the views' backgrounds to black eliminated the problem.

This would have been more obvious if iOS had simply left the underlying view in place, so we could see it through the "clear" overlying view. The fact that the underlying view moves up and partially off the screen to the left... and then stalls and just blinks out... doesn't seem intended.